# How to rotate a box2d body to face the direction it is traveling?

Tags: java, android, libgdx, box2d

I'm using `libgdx`/`box2d` and I have a ship object. I want to set the rotation of the ship's `body` so that it is always pointing towards the direction it is traveling.

The current approach I've taken towards this (and please do tell me if you know a better way) is to compare the ship's (x, y) position between the previous frame and the current frame, and then find the angle between the two.

However, my current position does not seem to be getting set correctly. The following code is happening within the `render()` method. As you can see, I'm setting `previousPosition = currentPosition`, and then I update `currentPosition`.

```
System.out.println("Current ONE: " + currentShipPosition.x + ", " + currentShipPosition.y);
System.out.println("Previous ONE: " + previousShipPosition.x + ", " + previousShipPosition.y);

float x = currentShipPosition.x;
float y = currentShipPosition.y;
previousShipPosition = new Vector2(x, y);

System.out.println("Current TWO: " + currentShipPosition.x + ", " + currentShipPosition.y);
System.out.println("Previous TWO: " + previousShipPosition.x + ", " + previousShipPosition.y);

currentShipPosition = ship.bodyWrapper.body.getWorldCenter();

System.out.println("Current THREE: " + currentShipPosition.x + ", " + currentShipPosition.y);
System.out.println("Previous THREE: " + previousShipPosition.x + ", " + previousShipPosition.y);

ship.setSpriteRotation(previousShipPosition, currentShipPosition);
```

At this point I would expect `Current ONE` and `Previous ONE` to be different, `Current TWO` and `Previous TWO` to be the same, and then `Current THREE` and `Previous THREE` to be different again. Here is a sample of the output:

```
Current ONE: -9.371556, 10.199657
Previous ONE: 7.4040437, 21.537455
Current TWO: -9.371556, 10.199657
Previous TWO: -9.371556, 10.199657
Current THREE: -9.371556, 10.199657
Previous THREE: -9.371556, 10.199657
Current ONE: 1.3700135, -0.12703675
Previous ONE: -9.371556, 10.199657
Current TWO: 1.3700135, -0.12703675
Previous TWO: 1.3700135, -0.12703675
Current THREE: 1.3700135, -0.12703675
Previous THREE: 1.3700135, -0.12703675
```

Why are the current and previous values on the third check the same and not updated until `render()` is called again? I would expect this to be updated properly on time.

Let me know if you need more code, or have any suggestions (related to the issue or otherwise). Thanks.

Edit: Okay, I have it working now, MUCH simpler with:
`float angle = (float) Math.atan2((double) body.getLinearVelocity().y, (double) body.getLinearVelocity().x);`
`body.setTransform(body.getWorldCenter(), angle - ((float)Math.PI)/2.0f);`

Comment: Can't you just use the body's velocity. By definition the velocity has direction.

Comment: atan(velocity.y, velocity.x)

Comment: Doh! I knew there must be a simple way to do it. I'm still very new to libgdx. Thank you Lionel, I will try that.

Comment: @LionelPort, I'm trying this but the problem is that whenever I try setting the angle via setTransform or setAngularVelocity, that seems the change the direction the body is moving in, not the rotation of the body.

Comment: @user3651349 What's the code you're using for the setTransform?

Comment: @Malkierian, I'm away atm, but something like body.setTransform(body.getWorldCenter (), angle). Angle being found how Lionel described

Comment: So it turns out when I changed my setSpriteAngle function, I was calculating the angle of the body but forgot to actually set the sprite angle... So that is fixed. However using LionelPort's suggestion, I'm still not getting the right angle of the body, it's just facing random directions, not pointed towards its movement

Comment: Okay, I have it working! What I said above only applies when using setAngularRotation, however using setTransform worked just fine (once I took pi/2 off the angle). Thank you guys

Comment: Yeah sorry didn't mention atan gives result in radians that you have to convert to degrees.